# Continuous heat map or Profile plotting in Pandas + Matplotlib + Seaborn using Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

[enter image description here][1]

the image shows .csv of data.The first column shows time axis.The next 6 columns various depths of current profile like s10,s20, s30, s50,s75,s100.

i am trying to plot continuos heatmap but i could do it as square or rectangle type of heatmap.

CODE I HAVE USED IS SHOWING BELOW

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("BD13.csv")

print(df.head(249))

heatmap_data = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['s10', 's20', 's30','s50', 's75','s100'], columns='time')

# PLOTTING BY USING SEABORN

sns.heatmap(heatmap_data, cmap="viridis", linewidths=.15)

**OR PLOTTING BY USING MATPLOTLIB**

plt.matshow(heatmap_data, interpolation='nearest', aspect='auto')
plt.show()
```

the above shown code works absolutely good for heatmap in form matrix seperation.But i need continuous heatmap can any one help me in it.

I am expecting like  continuous profile plot for various depths as shown in below link of data visualization of **4.Time series heatmap of temperature profile**

https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-data-visualization-with-python/

Can any one atleast give idea what to do.I am recent learner in python.It will be helpful for me.

thanks

janakiram

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes a toy dataset (refer to [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples))

Comment: Did you try `plt.contourf([10, 20, 30,50, 75,100], range(len(df)), heatmap_data)` or something similar (your exact data format is a bit unclear)?